# Twig PHP Pass existing Array to Twig Filter

Tags: php, twig

I'm trying to implement my custom Translation Filter in twig. All translations are stored in csv's. Per template we have a csv that contains the data.

Now for some reason the function within the filter isn't possible to access the $TranslationText array.

What should I change to make the filter working?

Notice: Undefined variable: TranslationText in /public_html/public/index.php on line 103

Translations are requested by {{ 'Whatever'|t}}

```
if (file_exists("../application/languages/nl/".$RenderTemplate.".csv") != FALSE) {
    $handle  = file_get_contents("../application/languages/nl/".$RenderTemplate.".csv");
    $handle_row = explode("\n", $handle);
    foreach ($handle_row as $key => $val) {
        $row_array = explode('|', $val);
        foreach ($row_array as $key => $val) {
            $row_array[$key] = trim(str_replace('"', '', $val));
        }
        $TranslationText[] = $row_array;
    }
}


require_once '../library/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../application/views/');
//Add Translation Filter
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('t', function ($string) {

    foreach($TranslationText AS $key => $value)//line 103
    {
        if($TranslationText[$key][0] == $string)
        {
            $Found = TRUE;
            $TranslatedText = $TranslationText[$key][1];
        }
    }

    if($Found == TRUE)
    {
        return $TranslatedText;
    }
    else
    {
        return $string;
    }

});


$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '../tmp/cache/', 'auto_reload' => TRUE, 'debug' => TRUE
));
//REMOVE auto_reload and DEBUG if live!
$twig->addFilter($filter);
echo $twig->render($RenderTemplate.".html", $TotalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can say is you get the error because of the following:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('t', function ($string) {
    foreach($TranslationText AS $key => $value)//line 103
    //... other code lines follow
});
```

You didn't `use` `$translationText`. Consider this code:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('t', function ($string) use ($TranslationText) {
    foreach($TranslationText AS $key => $value)//line 103
    //... other code lines follow
});
```

Please note that if your csv file doesn't exist or cannot be read, you will still get the same error, because you do not declare this variable outside your `file_exists` condition.

NB: I cannot guarantee that this is the only problem in your code. It's just a solution for your particular problem.

P.S. In general, your code looks messy. Consider using OOP for such things. Also, pay attention to the standards you use: some variables are named using underscores, others are named using CamelCase.